# Opening a popout (like lightbox) on page load

Tags: html

I'm using Weebly to build my site, simply for the easy content adding.

I created my theme in Dreamweaver and then uploaded it into Weebly.

Here's my question. A guy modified lightbox to work with Weebly so you could use the drag-and-drop feature with the popout.

I inserted the code he wanted me to, but I'm trying to get the popout to load when the page does, instead of having to click a link. Here's the html code that opens the popout when you click the link.

```
    <div id='basic-modal'>
    <a href='#' class='basic'>Open Popout</a>
    </div>
```

I'm a little confused, so please help. How would I do this?

Thanks.
- Ryan

Comment: Can you give a link to the page in action, or an example of the working page? EDIT: Please make sure you accept answers if some one helps you with your question (just looking at your first question)

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I'm new here with asking questions. An everyone is so helpful! You can visit the page at www.eastsidespeedway.weebly.com/index.html .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery Modal Tutorial that you could use to have a modal that loads with the page http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial

Click to see in action: [Demo](http://www.jacklmoore.com/demo/modal/modal2.html)

Please provide your jQuery script so others can try to help you with the code you're currently using.